# What is "chroma shift" in vpx_image_t struct of libvpx?

Tags: libvpx

libvpx codec operations use vpx_image_t structure for exchanging uncompressed frame data.
I got through understanding what majority of the members mean, but I'm stuck with `x_chroma_shift` and `y_chroma_shift`. The only explanation provided in the documentation is that it's "sub-sampling order". I am a newbie in YUV image formats, but I believe I understand what chroma sub-sampling is, but I can't quite figure out what does order of it mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider **(w, h)** YUV image (w and h are even numbers). Y plane size is also **(w, h)** but U/V plane size is **(w << x_chroma_shift, h << y_chroma_shift)** which is equivalent to **(w / (1 << x_chroma_shift), h / (1 << y_chroma_shift))**. Different chroma shift combinations define different YUV sub-samplings:

```
YUV   | x_chroma_shift | y_chroma_shift
======+================+===============
4:2:0 | 1              | 1
4:2:2 | 1              | 0
4:4:4 | 0              | 0
```

Comment: Interesting way to represent sub-sampling, thank you. But that would also make these members redundant, at least for input, along with `bps`, since them all determined by image type.

Comment: This is just a quick way to determine U/V plane width and height. In general, of course, you can use image type (vpx_img_fmt_t) for that. Note that bps is only for "packed" formats, not for "planar".